# How to mask sensitive data in a xml body with zalando.logbook

Tags: java, spring

Zalando.LogBook has some default mask filters but i haven't found one for xml bodies. I need to mask a password field (`<password>1234<\password>` -> `<password>masked<\password>`) in a xml body. Has any body implemented a body filter that can mask a passwort in a xml body?

```
  @Bean
  public Logbook getLogBook() {
    final Set<String> properties = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("password");

    return Logbook.builder()
        .bodyFilter(BodyFilters.replaceFormUrlEncodedProperty(properties, "<masked>"))
                                                 .build();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's [a class in logbook sources](https://github.com/zalando/logbook/blob/main/logbook-core/src/main/java/org/zalando/logbook/CompactingXmlBodyFilter.java) for compacting XMLs: `org.zalando.logbook.CompactingXmlBodyFilter`.

Just copy and paste it and make your own implementation of XML transform as in `removeEmptyTextNodes()`.

For example:

```
class LogbookXmlBodyPasswordFilter implements BodyFilter {
    [...]
    private void removePasswordTag(final Document document) throws Exception {
            final XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            final XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("Password", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                final Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
            }
        }
}
```

This method will remove any  `<Password>` tag from XML.

You can then use it like this:

```
 @Bean
 public BodyFilter bodyFilter() {
     return logbookXmlBodyPasswordFilter();
 }

 public static BodyFilter logbookXmlBodyPasswordFilter() {
     return new LogbookXmlBodyPasswordFilter();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Different approach that requires less code looks as follows:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
final class XmlFieldBodyFilter implements BodyFilter {

    private static final Predicate<String> XML = MediaTypeQuery.compile("*/xml", "*/*+xml");

    private final Collection<String> parameters;
    private final String replacement;

    @Override
    public String filter(@Nullable final String contentType, final String body) {
        return XML.test(contentType) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(body) ? censorBody(body) : body;
    }

    private String censorBody(final String body) {
        return parameters.stream().reduce(body, this::censorBody);
    }

    private String censorBody(String text, String parameterToReplace) {
        var pattern = compile("(<%s>)(.*)(</%s>)".formatted(parameterToReplace, parameterToReplace));
        var matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        var result = new StringBuilder(text.length());

        while (matcher.find()) {
            if (matcher.groupCount() == 3) {
                matcher.appendReplacement(result, String.join("", matcher.group(1), replacement, matcher.group(3)));
            }
        }
        matcher.appendTail(result);

        return result.toString();
    }

}

//Instance creation
new XmlFieldBodyFilter(List.of("Password"), "XXX");
```

It's based on regex. And solved issues I had with requirement to set `http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl` to false.